# Can I tell scala how to prefer more specific implicit, rather than give "ambiguous implicit" error?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, implicits

The following code gives an error.

```
class Base { }
class Sub extends Base { }

class Writer[-T] {
  def write(t: T) { }
}

object AmbImplicits {

  implicit object BaseWriter extends Writer[Base]
  implicit object SubWriter extends Writer[Sub]

  def foo[T](t: T)(implicit ev: Writer[T]) {
    println(s"foo $t $ev")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val base = new Base
    val sub = new Sub
    foo(base)
    foo(sub)
  }

}
```

The error:

```
/Workspace/AmbImplicits.scala:24: error: ambiguous implicit values:
both object SubWriter in object AmbImplicits of type AmbImplicits.SubWriter.type
and object BaseWriter in object AmbImplicits of type AmbImplicits.BaseWriter.type
match expected type Writer[Sub]
    foo(sub)
       ^
```

In my real code it is not so simple to explicitly pass the implicit parameter. Is there way to tell it to always prefer `SubWriter` over `BaseWriter`, because the former is more specific?  Without manually passing it like `foo(sub)(SubWriter)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't do what Shadowlands suggests due to Base and Sub being Java types, you can just reduce the priority of the `BaseWriter` implicit by moving it up the inheritance chain:

```
trait LowPriorityImplicits { implicit object BaseWriter extends Writer[Base] }

object AmbImplicits extends LowPriorityImplicits {
  implicit object SubWriter extends Writer[Sub]

  def foo[T](t: T)(implicit ev: Writer[T]) {
    println(s"foo $t $ev")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val base = new Base
    val sub = new Sub
    foo(base)
    foo(sub)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to, put the implicits in companion objects for each type derived from `Base`, rather than in the object with the `foo` method:

```
class Base { }
object Base { implicit object BaseWriter extends Writer[Base] }
class Sub extends Base { }
object Sub { implicit object SubWriter extends Writer[Sub] }

object NotAmbImplicits {

  def foo[T](t: T)(implicit ev: Writer[T]) {
    println(s"foo $t $ev")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val base = new Base
    val sub = new Sub
    foo(base)
    foo(sub)
  }

}
```

The compiler will look in the companion object for a given `T` passed to `foo` to see if it can use an implicit from there.

Comment: In reality the Base and Sub types are defined in Java.  But I may be able to port them.  Either way, this is helpful and I'll mark this as an answer at point, if I don't learn another way.